# HTML element show wrong area when there's no "border" attribute

Tags: html, css

I have a snippet of code that can be found here: https://jsfiddle.net/JaneChen/vn0n2058/

My HTML element shows a wrong top/bottom (when apply background-color, box-shadow), where there's a child element with relative position and margin-top, margin-bottom.

It shows "correct" (expected) area when adding "border: 2px red solid" to parent div.  In my jsfiddle code the parent div is "comment-input-wrapper".

```
border: 2px red solid;
```

Is there a solution or it's just a CSS bug...

HTML

```
<div class="comment-input-wrapper" >
    <div class="text-input-wrapper">
        abcdefg
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.comment-input-wrapper {
     box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px 0px rgba(181, 181, 181, 1);
    .text-input-wrapper {
         position: relative;
         margin-top: 30px;
         margin-bottom: 27px;
    }
}
```

Image:
[image: Wrong border]

Comment: whatever it was you cut/pasted from manged the text, and the .scss section is blank.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the weirder results of collapsing margins. https://css-tricks.com/what-you-should-know-about-collapsing-margins/#article-header-id-1.

Summary: The parent element's margin will override the child element's margin unless there is something solid between them. This could be another child element, or either a padding or border on the parent.

This dosn't mean 'something between the parent element and the child element' like one might think -- it means 'something between the margin of the parent element and the margin of the child element'  If you dig in to concept of the css box model, that will help explain why the parent's border and padding are between the margins of the parent and child elements.  (A good place to start on box model: https://css-tricks.com/the-css-box-model/)

If you want to accomplish this without a visible border, you could use 
`padding:1px;` on the parent, or `border:1px solid transparent;`

https://jsfiddle.net/t67359e0/ (uses padding in the example)

either way your parent will be 2px wider and 2px taller, but if you take 1px off the margin on each side of your child element, it will come out the same.

Lastly, you could also put the box-shadow on the child, and use padding instead of margin.

Hope that helps - happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

Removing your white space from your JS fiddle fixed some of it:
HTML:

```
<div class="comment-input-wrapper" >
<div class="text-input-wrapper">
abcdefg
</div>
</div>
```

Then I think using padding would give the desired centered effect:
CSS

```
.comment-input-wrapper {
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px 0px rgba(181, 181, 181, 1);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px 0px rgba(181, 181, 181, 1);
box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px 0px rgba(181, 181, 181, 1);
}

.text-input-wrapper {
position: relative;
padding-top: 30px;
padding-bottom: 27px;
width: auto;
padding-left: 50%;
}
```

If I understood your question correctly, I think this will help.

EDIT: Following on from comment

The margin has nothing to margin away from (I think), so won't show. If you place a div underneath the abcdefg div then it will put a nice gap as you needed. You coudl use padding instead to get desired effect if there are not more elements to add

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But this approach would change the border of the child element ( .text-input-wrapper) . .  I am more interested in finding the root cause , like if it's a css bug... or I did something wrong.   It's happening in several different browsers, so I think it's css's expected behavior. I want to learn from understanding why the outcome is like this.